# Port forwarding with wireguard

Tags: port-forwarding, wireguard

Using applications like qbittorrent and airdcpp to share files. They all need some ports to be forwarded in order to be "connectable".

In the home connection I would go into the router settings `192.168.1.1` and then forward the ports, ex. `56000` to my PC's local ip address: `192.168.1.124`. And the services would work alright.

Later set up wireguard on a Linode VPS wishing I can vpn into it and and mask my IP. But when I do that, my ip address is changed when I go to somewhere like https://whoer.net . But the ports used, ex. `56000` is not forwarded and thus the apps are not "connectable".

What are the things I need to add in iptables in order for the VPS to forward those ports like my home router does?

Port `56000` is set to `allow` in the active VPS `ufw` firewall.

Many thanks for looking.

This is what my VPS wireguard conf looks like:

```
Address = 10.66.66.1/24,fd42:42:42::1/64
ListenPort = 49503
PrivateKey = ***


[Peer]
PublicKey = ***
PresharedKey = ***
AllowedIPs = 10.66.66.2/32,fd42:42:42::2/128
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're using UFW, first make sure the UFW rule for port `56000` that you added is not a regular input rule, but instead a "route" (aka forwarding) rule, like this (assuming it's for a TCP port; replace `tcp` with `udp` for UDP):

```
ufw route allow proto tcp to 10.66.66.2 port 56000
```

Then you need an iptables rule like this for each port you want to forward (where `eth0` is the name of your WAN interface):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 56000 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.66.66.2
```

If you have a bunch of individual ports you want to forward, you can put them all (up to 15 ports) in the same rule using the `--dports` flag (note the `s`) of the `multiport` module:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 123,456,789 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.66.66.2
```

And since you're using UFW, you probably want to put your `PREROUTING` rules in the `*nat` block of your `/etc/ufw/before.rules` config file, like this (assuming you probably already have something similar to the `POSTROUTING` rule there):

```
# /etc/ufw/before.rules
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 56000 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.66.66.2
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

If you don't already have a `*nat` block in your `/etc/ufw/before.rules` file, add it at the end of the file. Restart UFW after you make the changes.

Comment: ufw is not capable of port forwarding? That's rather odd.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, it is just that you need to use iptables for forwarding, not that ufw can't. It is a firewall. So I guess you could say it can't but technically it isn't for that.

Comment: Thank you so much! You don't know how long and how much I gave agonized over this, because of how I didn't know of that rules to specifically let the ports to be forwarded. Guess I haven't been asking the question in the right exchange either. Was always in unix before I found out about serverfault. Again the answer is very appreciated!

Comment: Well, firewalld has port forwarding built in. About a year ago I migrated everything to firewalld, including Debian/Ubuntu systems, just to keep things consistent, as I have to manage a wide variety of distros. The larger feature set of firewalld and it being easier to manage via automation were compelling reasons to standardize on it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, is firewalld able to forward things like the answer does? I have used it on my local machine, though it is currently off as of now, I have used it to forward ports locally very conveniently with its GUI. Love it for that purpose, but don't know about what the iptables mentioned was able to do.

Comment: @Asmodean Yes, it both forwards ports and does masquerading itself.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, so I just don't know how to, can you look at this question? https://serverfault.com/questions/1068004/firewalld-forwarding-functionality-with-wireguard