# Firewalld Forwarding Functionality with Wireguard

Tags: port-forwarding, firewalld, wireguard

I have asked before how to forward ports on a VPS running a wireguard service with ufw and iptables as the management.

I had to do this:

(56000 is a random port I chose) (10.66.66.2 is the internal ip of wireguard)

```
ufw route allow proto tcp to 10.66.66.2 port 56000
```

Then I would do this to actually forward the ports with iptables:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 56000 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.66.66.2
```

Is there a way for me to achieve this with `firewalld` instead? so I won't have to separate the forwarding into two places?

And does masquerading come into use here/is it needed? Since I don't know what it does nor what it is used for.

VPS wireguard wg0 conf for reference purposes:

```
Address = 10.66.66.1/24,fd42:42:42::1/64
ListenPort = 49503
PrivateKey = ***


[Peer]
PublicKey = ***
PresharedKey = ***
AllowedIPs = 10.66.66.2/32,fd42:42:42::2/128
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your previous UFW question, sounds like you're using WireGuard for two purposes?: 1) forward traffic from a WireGuard client of your VPS out to the Internet, and 2) forward a few public ports from your VPS back to the WireGuard client. You need masquerading (aka SNAT) for 1) and port forwarding (aka DNAT) for 2).

The simplest way to set this up with firewalld is to bind your VPS's public Ethernet interface (`eth0` in your case) to firewalld's predefined `external` zone, and your VPS's WireGuard interface (`wg0` in your case) to firewalld's predefined `internal` zone. The `external` zone comes preconfigured with masquerading enabled; and both zones also come preconfigured to accept SSH and a few other services.

First open your VPS's WireGuard listen port (`49503` in your case) on the `external` zone:

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --zone=external --add-port=49503/udp
```

And forward port TCP `56000` on the `external` zone to the same port on `10.66.66.2`:

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --zone=external --add-forward-port='port=56000:proto=tcp:toaddr=10.66.66.2'
```

Then bind `eth0` to the `external` zone (which applies firewalld's configuration for the `external` zone to all `eth0` connections):

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --zone=external --add-interface=eth0
```

And bind `wg0` to the `internal` zone:

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --zone=internal --add-interface=wg0
```

Check your active zones:

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
external
  interfaces: eth0
internal
  interfaces: wg0
```

And check the configuration of your `external` zone:

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --info-zone=external
external (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth0
  sources:
  services: ssh
  ports: 49503/udp
  protocols:
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports: port=56000:proto=tcp:toaddr=10.66.66.2
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

If everything's working correctly, save your current firewalld settings:

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --runtime-to-permanent
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I use ssh on a different port, and with WG running I found that the clients could do anything they wanted except access public services on the VPS running WG, including ssh. The solution was to add the same `--add-port` command to the `internal` zone. I think in your answer it works because firewalld's internal and external zones both include the standard `ssh` service by default.