# wireguard docker, iptables and port forwarding to client

Tags: docker, nat, ufw, wireguard

I have a dedicated server running Ubuntu 22.04 with a wireguard (wg-easy) server running in docker.

*(ip addresses are examples)*

| Dedicated server | Wireguard Docker IP | Wireguard Client IP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 142.250.70.238 | 172.17.0.8 | 10.8.0.2 |

Connection to the wireguard server via both windows client and linux host works fine. They get their 10.8.0.x addresses and running a quick "what is my IP" search in google returns the expected `142.250.70.238` IP address.

Where I'm having trouble is port forwarding to a wireguard client. I'm trying to get traffic hitting `142.250.70.238` on `TCP 36029` to go to `10.8.0.2`.

From reading a number of other similar posts regarding wireguard port forwarding, this seems to be what I need but it doesn't work:
`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 36029 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.2`

I'm not sure if it's due to running the wireguard server in a docker, or because I'm relying on UFW to keep unwanted traffic out.

This post ([Port forwarding with wireguard](https://serverfault.com/questions/1067746/port-forwarding-with-wireguard)) has a simliar question regarding UFW (exluding docker) but that doesn't seem to work for me either:

`ufw route allow proto tcp to 10.8.0.2 port 36029`

Just wondering if one of you fine folk would be able to lend some assistance.

Thanks!

edit 1: so after thinking about it a bit more, i believe i need to configure the wireguard server docker to accept traffic from the desired incoming port

`-p 36029:36029`

Then a ufw rule to route any incoming traffic on `TCP 36029` to the host `142.250.70.238` to the wireguard docker:

`ufw route allow proto tcp from any to 172.17.0.8 port 36029`

I'm thinking the final step is to run an iptables in the docker container itself to the wireguard client on `10.8.0.2`

edit 2: using this command in the wireguard docker after doing the above worked:

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 36029 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.2`

Maybe running wireguard in docker is overcomplicating things for me...

Comment: With -p 36029:36029 you dont need DNAT since 36029 already accessible from outside and wg interface too. Check netstat -4npl to see it listen on 0.0.0.0:36029

Comment: You may have problems with default route - all traffic from conteiner will be routed via default route but with wg-quick should be ok